# ajax not working on mobile site

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hi everyone I have a script that has an ajax call within it.

```
$(document.body).on('click', '#postAppt', function (e) {

var serviceSelected = $("#selectServ option:selected").val();
var location = $('input[name="location"]:checked').val();
var price = $("#sessionPrice").val();
var date = $("#apptDate").val().replace(/\-/g, '');
var time = $("#time option:selected").val();

if(!$('input[name="location"]:checked').val()){
    alert("Please select a location!");
    return false;
}else{

    $("#schedulePhaseOne").hide();
    $("#schedulePhaseTwo").show();
    $("#goBackSP").show();

    var userid = $('div[id^="prfSchedule"').attr("id").replace("#", "").replace("prfSchedule","");

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "../users/functions.php?id=" + userid,
      data: {getServDetails: serviceSelected},
      cache: false,
      success: function(result){
          alert("success");
      }

    });
}

return false;

});
```

the ajax call only seems to work on desktop devices and not on mobile. I've been conflicted for a couple of hours now. Any suggestions? Also i want to load the contents (which are html) into a bootstrap modal. Could this also be a problem?

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting ?

Comment: I don't know how to view the console on the iphone...

Comment: Have u tried running your page in emulator. There you can get the error in the emulator console.

Comment: WHere is the emulator console?

Comment: Which emulator you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the problem of cross-domain.